# Laravel Multiple Signed Links Using Same Token

Tags: laravel

Is it possilbe to generated multiple signed links that use the same token using `URL::temporarySignedRoute()`

The reason I ask is because I want to send the frontend one single token that can be used to call multiple backend endpoints.

For example I have 4 endpoints that the frontend will call and I dont want to send 4 different tokens, I just want to send 1 token that can be used to authenticate all 4 endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. The token is an encrypted string of URL that signet route was generated for.